# Khmer unicode doesn't display correctly in Microsoft Client Side Report(rdlc)

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I building a winform application that records information using khmer unicode font. For my application i use c# with sqlserver and microsoft client report (rdlc) to generate reports. 
Now i have a problem with the rdlc report that does not display khmer unicode font correctly.
It displays like the image in the links below:

http://i1138.photobucket.com/albums/n522/sandeep251183/CRViewer.png

It should look like this

http://i1138.photobucket.com/albums/n522/sandeep251183/CRExportHTML-1.png

Can anyone find a solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many researches, I found some solutions for this problem.

1) If you use Dot Net Framework 3.5 windows Forms Application, Khmer Unicode font won't display properly in Microsoft Client Side report(rdlc report) but it works just fine with Microsoft Client Side report on Web Application because you may have new version of your browser that can handle this issue.

2) In Dot Net Framework 4.0 Microsoft Client Side report in either windows or web application works very well with Unicode.

3) For those of you who prefer Crystal report could apply a Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer Control with Crystal Report Business Object because Crystal Report that ships with Visual Studio 2008 or earlier has also the same problem as rdlc report with Khmer Unicode. Here is a link for using Crystal report with Khmer Unicode: http://computer-experience.blogspot.com/2008/12/khmer-unicode-with-crystal-report-in-c.html

4) I found a very cool feature of Text Quality field property on [StimulSoft](http://stimulsoft.com/) Report, which can be changed to Standard, Typographic or Wysiwyg that totally support with unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, computer-experience blog was moved to http://osify.com/2008/12/khmer-unicode-with-crystal-report-in-c-application/#.Ub54tDfL7Uk and source code download available again.

Answer (score 0):

Khmer rendering has a couple of issues depending on which technology you use to display it. Have a look at [Khmer-related posts on Sorting It All Out](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3ahttp://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap%20khmer).