# Unicode Characters not display correctly in the converted pdf file using xhtml2pdf library

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab, xhtml2pdf

I am using xhtml2pdf library to convert my webpage into an pdf document. The library function was working fine, however since the webpage contents is an Khmer unicode, the produced pdf document content was not correctly display.

Here is the result pdf file:

[image: Result of produced pdf file]

The correct content should be

ភាសាខ្មែរ

នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទសាមញ្ញជាភាសាខ្មែរដែលបានសរសេរជាអក្សរខ្មែរយូនីកូដ។

Here is my python code to convert to pdf file:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import io

def convert_html_to_pdf(source_html, output_filename):
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as output_file:
        pdf_status = pisa.CreatePDF(source_html, dest=output_file)

    return not pdf_status.err

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with io.open("khmer_unicode.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as html_file:
        html_content = html_file.read()

    pdf_output = "khmer_unicode.pdf"
    if convert_html_to_pdf(html_content, pdf_output):
        print "PDF file has been created at "+pdf_output
    else:
        print("Error generating PDF")
```

and my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>sample file</title>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'KhmerOS';
            src: url('KhmerOS.ttf');
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'KhmerOS', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ភាសាខ្មែរ</h1>
    <p>នេះគឺជាអត្ថបទសាមញ្ញជាភាសាខ្មែរដែលបានសរសេរជាអក្សរខ្មែរយូនីកូដ។</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The font file 'KhmerOS.tff' is in the same directory.

Do I have to encode anything more to make the Khmer Unicode character to display correctly in the converted file? Please kindly help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reading "[Fonts and encodings](https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch3_fonts/)" you might have to use the `pdfmetrics` module from the `reportlab` package to register the font first, before using it with `xhtml2pdf`:

```py
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import io
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

def convert_html_to_pdf(source_html, output_filename):
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('KhmerOS', 'KhmerOS.ttf'))
    with open(output_filename, "wb") as output_file:
        pdf_status = pisa.CreatePDF(source_html, dest=output_file)

    return not pdf_status.err

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with io.open("khmer_unicode.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as html_file:
        html_content = html_file.read()

    pdf_output = "khmer_unicode.pdf"
    if convert_html_to_pdf(html_content, pdf_output):
        print "PDF file has been created at %s" % pdf_output
    else:
        print "Error generating PDF"
```

That code registers the `KhmerOS.ttf` font with `reportlab` which should then be available for `xhtml2pdf` to use when creating the PDF.
If the Khmer Unicode characters are still not displaying correctly, it could be an issue with the font file itself.

---

> I have tested with registered font function already and tried the different font, but it was still the same.

That means your current process pipeline need to change.

You can try and convert the text to a format that is known to work well with [`xhtml2pdf`](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). For example, you could try converting the Khmer Unicode text to HTML entities.

Or you might consider using a PDF creation library (like `reportlab`) directly, without going through HTML. You could create a PDF template and then insert your text into that template.

But you can also try a Different HTML to PDF Library, like [`pdfkit`](https://pdfkit.org/) or [`weasyprint`](https://weasyprint.org/). These libraries may handle Unicode characters more reliably.

Example using `pdfkit` library:

```py
import pdfkit
import io

def convert_html_to_pdf(source_html, output_filename):
    pdfkit.from_file(source_html, output_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    html_content = "khmer_unicode.html"
    pdf_output = "khmer_unicode.pdf"
    convert_html_to_pdf(html_content, pdf_output)
```

To use `pdfkit`, you will need to install [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).
Then install the `pdfkit` Python package with `pip install pdfkit`.

Comment: thank you, I have tested with registered font function already and tried the different font, but it was still the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I could not use that library, its size is too large to use on remote server. Thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun I understand. That would have been just for testing, in order to validate if the issue was with your current library.

Comment: the libraries pdfkit and  wkhtmltopdf were working fine as tested by team. and one more thing, when change extension of output file from *.pdf to *.doc, the text is rendered correctly in word processing document (ms.word). I don't know why it problem with pdf file. I found people also has problem like me too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412249/khmer-unicode-doesnt-display-correctly-in-microsoft-client-side-reportrdlc but they used different programming language. Thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun So how about generating the document in a different format that does support Khmer Unicode text correctly, such as Word or HTML? You could then provide a tool or instructions for the user to convert the document to PDF themselves, using a tool that you know works correctly with Khmer Unicode, such as a modern web browser's "Print to PDF" feature.

Alternatively, you could consider implementing a solution using a technology that does support Khmer Unicode correctly in PDFs, such as LaTeX or a browser-based PDF generation library like Puppeteer in Node.js.

Comment: I did not use other beside  ```reportlab``` and  ```xhtml2pdf``` I just change the line of code ```pdf_output = "khmer_unicode.pdf"``` to ```pdf_output = "khmer_unicode.doc"``` that I said it render correct in file Word Document. But I want it work the same in the pdf file. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254417/discussion-between-vonc-and-houy-narun).